# Disable field when current user isn't line manager

Tags: javascript, permissions, designer-workflow

I've been searching for a couple of hours now and not found anything useful or that fully answers my query.

I have a new approval process for holidays but I need some assistance locking down the status of the request so people cannot approve their own holiday. Therefor I need either JS or SPD workflow to change a field called "status" to disabled/grey on the new and edit forms, this should fire if the Current User does not match "Line Manager" field. I'm using WSS3/SPD2007.

Thanks

Comment: SharePoint doesn't have column level permissions so you can't technically lock down a field (just an item itself). Adjusting permissions on an item can be done from a workflow, but if you just want to adjust the display/logic of the form then you'll need a customized form.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm happy to customise the form, Is there a good tutorial you'd recommend? I'll start looking in the meantime.